# How to install sbt-sh plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh

I'm using sbt 0.13.9 and try to install sbt-sh with given instructions. However sbt does not recognize sh command:

```
> sh ls
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: sh
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: sh
[error] sh ls
[error]   ^
>
```

Instructions are for sbt 0.10, maybe things have changed since those days and this guide is out of date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are a bit outdated. Instead of `~/.sbt/plugins/project`, you should put the MyPlugins object in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/project/MyPlugins.scala`.

However, sbt-sh doesn't seem to work, even with that correction:

```
[error] $HOME/.sbt/0.13/staging/1375c2d4ab8153e18523/sbt-sh/src/main/scala/org/sbtsh/SbtShPlugin.scala:4: object CommandSupport is not a member of package sbt
[error] import sbt.CommandSupport._
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] ({git://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh.git}sbt-sh/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Can you try [xsbt-sh](https://github.com/melezov/xsbt-sh) instead?

Create a file `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/xsbt-sh.sbt` with this content:

```
resolvers += "Element Releases" at "http://repo.element.hr/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("hr.element.xsbt" % "xsbt-sh" % "0.0.2")
```

The Github README refers to 0.1.0 but that doesn't seem to have been yet released to the repository.